# Clear the form/textarea after submit (emoji-picker with jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, emoji

In my `form/textarea` I use an emoji picker (https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea).
Idea is once user write some text/put some emoji and send this (“Submit”) the form will reset/clear.

**My ongoing code: https://jsfiddle.net/byrvfwah/**

**Emoji picker works well, but I can’t clear the form after submit.**

At the same time, **without function which initiates an emoji-picker, the submit button clear the form: https://jsfiddle.net/9bps7f6v/3/**

There are a lot of method to reset form and I already tried a lot of them:

```
$("#mytextarea").val('');
$('#mytextarea').trigger("reset");
$(‘#mytextarea').text('');
$("#mytextarea").reset();
$("#myform")[0].reset();
```

The explanations from the author of emoji-picker script not very useful:

https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea/issues/9

https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea/issues/54

https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea/issues/373

Any ideas how I can clear my form on submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target **emojionarea-editor** class div and replace with empty '' string.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytextarea").emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom"
});
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".emojionearea-editor").html('');

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is correct and it works fine in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kady28r9/
Unfortunately it still not working on my production site, don’t know why((( Anyway, you put me on the right path (I didn’t see this nested div container “.emojionarea-editor”. Thanks!

Comment: mention not,thanks for your appreciation.Please,mark as a answer and up-vote,if you don't bother.

Comment: clear the cache file from your browser, cntrl+f5 to reload your browser to get new version of your production level's stuff.

Comment: My bad! It works fine on production site now. I just had some remains of my “attempts code”. After clean my code, it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not being cleaned **because it is not a data input element** rather it is a div. Inspecting the item you can see:

[image]

And has a class, so you can just clear the html:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       $(".emojionearea-editor").html('');
     });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually he is similar to the answer of Muhammad Amirozzaman Niaz, who was first. So I have to accept his answer. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mytextarea").data("emojioneArea").setText('');
```